# Unable to install Julia packages

Tags: package, julia

I am unable to install julia packages, can you help? I get the following error message

```
julia> Pkg.add("XGBoost")
INFO: Cloning cache of XGBoost from https://github.com/dmlc/XGBoost.jl.git
ERROR: Cannot clone XGBoost from https://github.com/dmlc/XGBoost.jl.git. failed
to send request: The server name or address could not be resolved

 in prefetch(::String, ::String, ::Array{String,1}) at .\pkg\cache.jl:56
 in resolve(::Dict{String,Base.Pkg.Types.VersionSet}, ::Dict{String,Dict{Version
Number,Base.Pkg.Types.Available}}, ::Dict{String,Tuple{VersionNumber,Bool}}, ::D
ict{String,Base.Pkg.Types.Fixed}, ::Dict{String,VersionNumber}, ::Set{String}) a
t .\pkg\entry.jl:512
 in resolve(::Dict{String,Base.Pkg.Types.VersionSet}, ::Dict{String,Dict{Version
Number,Base.Pkg.Types.Available}}, ::Dict{String,Tuple{VersionNumber,Bool}}, ::D
ict{String,Base.Pkg.Types.Fixed}) at .\pkg\entry.jl:476
 in edit(::Function, ::String, ::Base.Pkg.Types.VersionSet, ::Vararg{Base.Pkg.Ty
pes.VersionSet,N}) at .\pkg\entry.jl:30
 in (::Base.Pkg.Entry.##2#5{String,Base.Pkg.Types.VersionSet})() at .\task.jl:36
0
 in sync_end() at .\task.jl:311
 in macro expansion at .\task.jl:327 [inlined]
 in add(::String, ::Base.Pkg.Types.VersionSet) at .\pkg\entry.jl:51
 in (::Base.Pkg.Dir.##2#3{Array{Any,1},Base.Pkg.Entry.#add,Tuple{String}})() at
.\pkg\dir.jl:31
 in cd(::Base.Pkg.Dir.##2#3{Array{Any,1},Base.Pkg.Entry.#add,Tuple{String}}, ::S
tring) at .\file.jl:48
 in #cd#1(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::String, ::Vararg{Any,N}) at
.\pkg\dir.jl:31
 in add(::String) at .\pkg\pkg.jl:100
```

I have tried

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

This hasn't helped. I am connecting at work. Looks like a proxy / firewall issue.

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

I am using windows 7, julia 0.5.0, git 2.10.1.windows.1.

I can manually download the zip from the webpage.

Comment: Which version of Julia? Do you have an http proxy? Does it need authentication?

Comment: using `Pkg.add("XGBoost")` seems to work for me. note that it will require OpenMP. did you try cloning the repo and then building it? from the [XGBoost.jl website](https://github.com/dmlc/XGBoost.jl): `Pkg.clone("https://github.com/antinucleon/XGBoost.jl.git"); 
Pkg.build("XGBoost")`